# Overlocker tension discs threading

Tags: sewing

I have an Singer Overlock 14SH754 Sewing Machine but I'm not sure that my thread is routed correctly, as the tension seems off.

Can I confirm that the thread routes through the "tension discs" in-between the metal discs, and not between the plastic dial and metal disc?

[image]

Comment: I think you should be including the make and model of your machine for question like this. That way answers will have something concreate (in theory) to reference.

Comment: Based on the image, this looks like an exact match for the [Singer Overlock 14SH754 Sewing Machine](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Singer-Overlock-14SH754-Sewing-Machine/dp/B0036U4LB0). If this is incorrect and the OP addresses it, we can adjust, otherwise, let's pretend this is the machine to write an answer about.

Answer (score 3):

Overlock machines (aka sergers) can be very fickle depending on the fabric that you are using. It is a **must** to have your manual near by and scraps of fabric to sample before starting your project. Especially since a serger will cut the fabric edges when the knife is in place. 

Your manual will give you alternate settings and tips for the tension knobs that you show in your picture as well as the feed dog tension. You can also play with the tension to make the serged edges ruffle, especially with knits.

ALSO, be careful with knits! They can really mess up a machine - don't pull or push the fabric in, always let the feed dogs take the knit material.

Answer (score 1):

I have confirmed that I was right and that the thread should go between the metal discs.

Comment: Did the manual confirm this for you? It might be worth adding in some images or more information in case some people can't follow your description.

Comment: How did you confirm this?